# Java code is for Posting variables to php script, and it isnt working, getting 403 error

Tags: java, php, html, post

I have a fun challenge. I have to send the password "flubergump" to a page on the net (php script).

I wrote this common code:

```
try {

    URL url = new URL(A);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    F = URLEncoder.encode(F, "UTF-8");
    writer.write(F);
    System.out.println(F);
    String line;

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (con.getInputStream ());

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        G=G + line;
    }
    textarea.setText(G);
    writer.close();
    in.close();
```

and tried sending every version of password = flubergump!

Sending this HTML would work:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.hackthis.co.uk/levels/i2.php">
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="flubergump">
</form>
```

But I wanted to make a "post variables" tool, simply in the name of practice. Can you help by telling me why I'm not getting any success. I tried writing my own PHP scripts and I'm still having no luck. I've researched this topic to death, and one would get the impression that this code is supposed to work.

Comment: "still getting no luck" LOL you can see im not going to get anywhere if I think luck is going to help me code :P

Comment: I cant use "setRequestMethod (POST)" my compiler thinks it doesn't exist, is this a thing?

Comment: You say it's php-code but it looks like java?

Comment: OH no I have forgot to state that its java:/ brain must be really frazzled sry

Comment: But then of course it won't work with your form with action="l2.php"

Comment: "Setting the URLConnection#setDoOutput() to true means that you're about to write request data to the request body"

Comment: What is the value of F? (I think it should be `password=flubergump`)

Comment: @JethroDevøn - I don't understand the problem. You can't mix different languages in which manner you want. A php script would look like <?php echo $_POST['password'];?> and echo out "flubergump" to the browser.

Comment: If your java code is supposed to send a POST request, maybe the first answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily) should get you started.

Comment: yes thats right flup, Im not sure what you mean martin, I have written a java code that sends "password=flubergump" to the php scripts in URL, am I in the PHP part od stack overflow by mistake and not the java one? im so confused

Comment: oh "this question" was a link, I thought you were being cryptic

Comment: no these dont help, I have copied what works for other people and still not got the desired result (I have looked for the answer hard and only found people using identicle code to me and having great success, what is it that "bestprogrammerintheworld"is getting at, can i not post to these guys??)